# Apache Web server sending <html> tags for Json Response

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, apache, webserver

I have a simple Ajax call like

```
  $('#getOrgs').on('click', function() { 
        var form_data=new FormData(document.getElementsByName('f_xmlupdates')[0]);      
            $.ajax({
                url: 'ajax/getOrgs.php', 
                dataType: 'json', 
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: form_data,                       
                type: 'post',
                success: function(php_script_response){
                    $('#atscale_org').empty();
                    jQuery.each( php_script_response, function( i, val ) {
                        $('#atscale_org').append($('<option></option>').val(val[0]).html(val[1]));
                    });
                        $('#getOrgs').css('background','dimgrey');
                },
                    error: function ( error ) {
                        console.log("Something Wrong with GetOrgs..."+JSON.stringify(error));
                }
            });
});
```

Php Side - getOrgs.php

```
    <?php 
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    include('../utils/utils.php');
    $organization = get_orgs_from_pg( $_POST["atscale_server"] );
    echo json_encode($organization,TRUE);
    exit();
    ?>
```

I am using Apache WebServer 2.4.29 .This above code fills a select box. This works fine most of the day , sometimes (Once in few days) Ajax call goes into Error block instead of Success block. I see ServerState:4 error message. And I see the response from PHP has  tags starting with

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head> 
<body>
{json Response}
</body>
</html>
```

The issue goes away once I restart the Apache Web Server. Can someone give me any pointers , which process is adding the HTML tags ? and why Its happening suddenly?

Comment: You kinda just said the problem cause where if there's an error on server end, then you dont get xml.... In such case you can parse that result as if it were not pure xml. Maybe on an error look for body tags to decipher the html/xml there?

Comment: Also no idea what this `get_orgs_from_pg()` does. Its like a black box. Impossible to debug.

Comment: the process adding the HTML tags is the server providing the fallback, default content that it is configured to send back when it doesn't recognize a request.

Comment: @GetSet function get_orgs_from_pg() just returns few rows from postgres

 while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result))
                    {
                        array_push($resp, array(
                            htmlentities($row[0], ENT_XHTML) ,
                            htmlentities($row[1], ENT_XHTML),
                            htmlentities($row[2], ENT_XHTML)
                        ));
                    }
                }
                return $resp;
is htmlentities , adding those <HTML> tags on the json response ? I am going to remove htmlentities and try.

Comment: I will try to remove the htmlentities , when I hit the error again. Right now ajax is receiving the json response correctly.

Comment: Looks like the issue was with "htmlentities($row[2], ENT_XHTML) )" method within my php function. When I remove it i can see the error is getting resolved. Thanks all for your comments !!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue was with "htmlentities($row[2], ENT_XHTML) )" method within my php function. When I remove it i can see the error is getting resolved. Thanks all for your comments !!